# Why does javac allow fields to be defined after methods that use them in a class?

Tags: java, jvm, javac

I have noticed that when you execute a statement like `sum=a+b;`
we need the three fields initialized prior to using them in this operation
ie

```
int a=1 
int b=1;
int sum=0;
sum=a+b;
```

.
My understanding is, this is because javac works like an interpreter and reads line by line.
But when it comes to methods where we call and pass values to fields inside a class we can define the fields after method declaration.

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
public Dog(String name, int weight, int teeth, String coat) {
    super(name, true, true, weight);
    this.tail=true;
    this.eyes=2;
    this.teeth=teeth;
    this.coat=coat;

}

private int eyes;
private boolean tail;
private int teeth;
private String coat;}
```

The parameters eyes, tail, teeth, and coat have been defined after they were used to pass values to the constructor.
How does javac understand that there is a variable after the method.
Is this allowed because we can only define fields and not do any operations on them in a class definition?

Comment: `javac` does not work like an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

**Javac is Java Compiler** Compiles your Java code into Bytecode

**JVM is Java Virtual Machine** Runs/ Interprets/ translates Bytecode into Native Machine Code

This error occurs only with local variables because the compiler does not set the default value for the local variables. In the case of instance variables, the compiler sets default values, for example, 0 for integer, null for string, etc.

In the above case if you don't set values in the constructor still your instance variables will be initialized by default values.

```
private int eyes = 0;
private boolean tail = false;
private int teeth = 0;
private String coat = null;
```

But same is not true for local variables a, b or sum.
sum can be uninitialized because you are assigning the values to the sum before using it. That is the statement `sum = a+b`  will assign value and before you use it somewhere else may be like `sum2 = sum`, its assured that sum has a value.

Answer (score 0):

A local variable declaration (and eventual initialization) is *executed* together with the block it is in, and being accessed from;
an instance field declaration (and initialization) is *executed* when the instance is created, before the methods are executed <sup>**1**</sup>.

On the other side this is not allowed:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    private int total = eyes + teeth;  // ERROR!
    private int eyes = 2;
    private int teeth = 24;
}
```

<sup>above code does not compile - that is intentional!</sup>

while this is valid:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    private int eyes = 2;
    private int teeth = 24;
    private int total = eyes + teeth;  // OK
}
```

---

*Why ...?* Short answer: it is specified that way, see Java Language Specification (JLS) - [Scope of a Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a declaration of a member m declared in ...  a class or interface C (§8.2, §9.2) is the **entire body of C**, ...

> The scope of a local variable declared in a block by a local variable declaration statement (§14.4.2) is the **rest of the block**,...

One reasons for that is to avoid cyclic references as mentioned in the JLS, see examples on link below <sup>**1**</sup>. Also explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68234575/16320675) by [Hoopje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142130/hoopje).

---

**1** - exception are references to fields in initializers, see [Restrictions on Field References in Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3)

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with the difference between an interpreter and a compiler. It is just a rule added to language to prevent two fields to refer to each other in their initialization code. For example, what would be the initial values of the fields in the following class?

```
class A {
    int a = b * b;
    int b = a + 1;
}
```

Of course, the Java designers could have decided to allow forward references, and only generate an error when such cycles are detected. But they decided otherwise, and I think that that was the right decision.

There is no reason to forbid forward references to fields from within a method, because when the method is executed, the class is initialized already. Even constructors run after the fields' initializers have been evaluated.